# `foreman start` on Scala project, can't find main class - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, foreman

I'm trying to test out my app before deploying it on Heroku. I've added the sbt start script to my plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.8.0")
```

And I have a `Procfile` containing:

> web: target/start Web -Dhttp.port=$PORT

When I run the sbt `stage` task, it generates the start script in `target/start` which points to the "main" class of my project, in the form of com.somepackage.mainclass.

When I run `foreman start` though, it immediately fails with:

> 08:34:51 web.1  | Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: foo/launch/MainApp 08:34:51 web.1  |
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.launch.MainApp
>   08:34:51 web.1  |     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 08:34:51 web.1 
>   |     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   08:34:51 web.1  |     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 08:34:51
>   web.1  |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>   08:34:51 web.1  |     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) 08:34:51
>   web.1  |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>   08:34:51 web.1  | exited with code 1 08:34:51 system | sending SIGTERM
>   to all processes

I've tried sbt clean compile stage several times, but it doesn't seem to help. Neither does moving the main class to a different package or even to the default package, i.e. src/main/scala.